# SQL select where value not matched

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have 2 tables.  One is `people` with name, ssn, etc.  The other is `cars` with ssn, make, model, etc.

How would I go about selecting from the `people` table where the ssn column doesn't match with any ssn from the `cars` table?

The combined table has `ssn, name, etc, carssn, carid`, and anyone that doesn't have a ssn on the `cars` table has NULL for those 2 columns when the tables are joined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from people p
where not exists (select 1 from cars c where c.ssn = p.ssn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not in`:

```
select *
from people
where ssn not in (select ssn from cars);
```

If you want to use a join, as described in the question, use `is null`:

```
select p.*
from people p
left join cars c using (ssn)
where c.ssn is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `ALL` as well

```
select *
from people
where ssn != ALL(select ssn from cars);
```

if `ssn` in `cars` is never `NULL`. If `ssn` is sometimes `NULL` than you might use

```
select *
from people
where ssn != ALL(select ssn from cars where ssn IS NOT NULL);
```

You should worry about `NULL`s also in solution using `NOT IN`